# updateOrCreate - Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, list, request, controller, tags

I just started learning Laravel. I can't figure out how to update the data in the table. There is a table:

[image]

I want to insert the entry: machine_name + number_of_shifts. At the same time, if there is a machine_name record, then the number_of_shifts value must be updated for this record. Or, if there is no record, then create a new machine_name + number_of_shifts.

As a result, the error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause' (SQL: update `machines` set `machine_name` = Станок 456, `machines`.`updated_at` = 2023-01-16 20:52:34 where `id` is null)

What did I prescribe wrong?????? HELP ME FIGURE IT OUT, please.

Controller Code StoreController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Machines;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\Machine;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class StoreController extends Controller
{
   public function __invoke(Request $request){


    $data = request()->validate([
            'machine_name' => '',
            'number_of_shifts' => '',
        ]);

 Machine::updateOrCreate(['number_of_shifts' => $request->input('number_of_shifts')], $data);

        return redirect()->route('machine.index');
    }

}
```

Code create.blade

```
@extends('layouts.main')

@section('title-block') Добавить станок @endsection

@section('content')

<div class="d-flex p-2">

<form action="{{ route('machine.store') }}" method="post">
@csrf


  <div class="mb-3">
    <label for="machine_name" class="form-label">Станок</label>
    <input type="text" name="machine_name" class="form-control" id="machine_name" placeholder="Станок 1">
  </div>
  
  <div class="mb-3">
    <label for="number_of_shifts" class="form-label">Количество смен</label>
    <input type="text" name="number_of_shifts" class="form-control" id="number_of_shifts" placeholder="1">
  </div>

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark">Добавить станок</button>

  <a class="btn btn-dark" href="{{ route ('machine.index') }}" role="button">Назад</a>

</form>

</div>

@endsection
```

Migration Code:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

return new class extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('machines', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id('machine_id');
            $table->string('machine_name', 255);
            $table->bigInteger('number_of_shifts')->unsigned()->nullable()->default(0);
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->softDeletes();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('machines');
    }
};
```

Comment: try adding `protected $primaryKey = 'machine_id';` to your Machine.php model

Comment: Personally, I would go for primary key `id` in stead of `machine_id`. It works great with laravel out of the box(also for relationships) and when manually querying for tests or analisys, `join sometable s on s.machine_id = machines.id` looks better to me than `join sometable s on s.machine_id = machines.machine_id`

Answer (score 0):

If you have changed the primary key name then you most define in model like this.

```
protected $primaryKey = 'machine_id';
```

And this is the bad idea to change its primary key.